# log4net used in VSTO Add-In will not write to file if the Add-In is under HKLM

Tags: outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, log4net, office-addins

**ENVIRONMENT**

- VS2022
- OFFICE 365
- log4net 2.0.15

**ISSUE**:
I wrote a VSTO Add-In for Outlook and installed log4net as a NuGet package.

What I noticed is that when the Add-In is installed under HKCU, log4net writes to my log files just fine;
this includes internal debugging.

However, we would like to have the Add-In installed on a per-machine basis (HKLM).  Under HKLM log4net does not write anywhere; even when I turn on the internal debugging.

NOTE: The following snippet works fine when the VSTO Add-In is installed under HKCU

```
   <log4net>
    <appender name="RollingFileAppenderAddin" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="%envFolderPath{UserProfile}\\MyLogs\\MyLog.txt" />
```

Comment: In case of HKLM, is your addin installed in Program Files or some other folder where regular users have no write access?

Comment: The Add-In is installed under Program Files (x86)\<custom Folder>\
We are running 64-bit Win10 and 32-Bit Outlook

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko
I've updated the question and added a snippet from my config file.

Comment: Try to run ProcMon and see if it attempts to write to some other location.

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko:  Thanks.   I'll give procmon a go and let you know how it goes.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't actually matter where the add-in is registered - HKCU or HKLM. That matters to Outlook only.

In case of logging files you need to pay attention whether the host application is run with admin privileges or not. Depending on that a different value for the `UserProfile` environment variable will be used. For example, if you run your add-in from VS under the debugger attached with admin privileges it can be a different user (admin). For a better understanding where the file is created I'd suggest using the [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) utility which can shed the light where the file is created.

Comment: Good Info.   One thing to know.   I was also trying to hardcode values to different areas on my disk  (e.g.  C:\Logs\,   D:\MyLogs\Logs, etc.).   I was thinking "userprofile" would not easily be available to Add-Ins registered under HKLM without elevated privileges.

Comment: Again, it doesn't matter where the add-in was registered.

Comment: I re-read your comment more closely.   So, it's possible for Outlook to use a different value for the Environment variable depending on the mode it's run in?  For example:
ADMIN MODE: %userprofile% = "Users\MyAccount"   NON-ADMIN MODE: %userprofile%= something different.

Comment: Try using the process monitor utility mentioned in my post for searching where the file is created when it is absent where you expect to find it.